# Systemctl unable to start service in Docker because of its service exec type

Tags: docker

Whiole trying to start the `gsad` service in a Docker container, I'm receiving the following error:

```
root@7146c6073ae5:/# systemctl start gsad.service                          
ERROR:systemctl: gsad.service: Failed to parse service type, ignoring: exec
ERROR:systemctl:unsupported run type 'exec'
```

Here's the original `/etc/systemd/system/gsad.service` file, which is based on the original [documentation](https://greenbone.github.io/docs/latest/22.4/source-build/index.html#setting-up-services-for-systemd):

```
[Unit]
Description=Greenbone Security Assistant daemon (gsad)
Documentation=man:gsad(8) https://www.greenbone.net
After=network.target gvmd.service
Wants=gvmd.service

[Service]
Type=exec
User=gvm
Group=gvm
RuntimeDirectory=gsad
RuntimeDirectoryMode=2775
PIDFile=/run/gsad/gsad.pid
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/gsad --foreground --listen=127.0.0.1 --port=9392 --http-only
Restart=always
TimeoutStopSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=greenbone-security-assistant.service
```

My base image for the `Dockerfile` is `ubuntu:latest` and I've built openvas using that article from the source.

While I'm not sure this is contributing to the error, I received `systemctl` by performing the following in my `Dockerfile` in the very beginning:

```
  git clone https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement /opt/systemctl-github && \
  ln -s /opt/systemctl-github/files/docker/systemctl3.py /usr/bin/systemctl
```

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process.  It usually doesn't run systemd or another init system, and normally commands like `systemctl` just don't work at all.  Trying to start a background service via a debugging shell isn't the most common container setup; can you run this process as the main container `CMD`, in the foreground, without involving systemd at all?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're not actually running `systemctl` from Systemd (in which support for the `exec` service type was introduced back in 2018). You're using the `systemctl` command provided by https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement, which doesn't understand the `exec` service type (you can see the list of supported types [here](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement/blob/master/files/docker/systemctl.py#L5054)).

There doesn't seem to be much point to using this wrapper: just take the `ExecStart` command from your service file and make that the `CMD` entry in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

.
.
.

CMD /usr/local/sbin/gsad --foreground --listen=127.0.0.1 --port=9392 --http-only
```

You can add the necessary `USER`, `WORKDIR`, etc directives to reproduce the environment configured by your service file.

You'll probably want to change that `--listen` option; in almost all cases it doesn't make sense to bind to the localhost address inside a container.

---

It looks like the Greenbone project provides their own Docker images, along with instructions for running things in a containerized environment. The documentation is at https://greenbone.github.io/docs/latest/22.4/container/index.html.

Comment: Thanks. I changed "exec" to "simple" and it seems to have done the trick thus far. Although, I'm not sure if there are other issues that might stem from this. Unfortunately, the openvas docker setup isn't feasible for what I'm trying to do. They have multiple containers, which is what I'm trying to avoid by having a single Dockerfile.